# Floating point comparison in while loop with modulus

Tags: c++, loops, floating-point, modulus

I would like some advise on how to optimise the following while loop:

```
double minor_interval   = 0.1;
double major_interval   = 1.0;

double start            = 0.0;
double finish           = 10.0;

printf("Start\r\n");

while (start < finish)
{
    printf("Minor interval: %.20f\r\n", start);

    double m = fmod(start, major_interval);
    printf("m: %.20f\r\n", m);

    if (m == 0)
        printf("At major interval: %.20f\r\n", start);

    start += minor_interval;
}

printf("Finished\r\n");
```

Essentially, I am incrementing a counter in the loop by the minor interval and would like to know every time around the loop if I am at a major interval. Picture this as drawing a ruler with millimeter intervals, and every time I get to a major interval, I want to draw a centimetre. Given inaccuracies in floating point arithmetic, how can I modify the above loop to implement the functionality I require? I have tried different methods of comparing the result of the modulus using a tolerance with no luck. Note that the minor and major intervals can be any values i.e. minor = 0.4 and major = 1.6 (to draw quarter mile increments).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your numbers are only correct to 2 decimal point, why don't you multiply all the numbers by 100 and go for the much precise integer arithmetic?
For integers, [div](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/div/) or [ldiv](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/ldiv/).

Comment: @Ron Inches scales would often have 1/8 or 0.125 increments. Why settle for imperfect solutions when it is trivially easy to avoid such limitations as you suggest.

Comment: @David I avoid floating-pointing arithmetic unless there's no way to avoid or it cost much efficiency to implement in integer arithmetic. I was just suggesting if the numbers do limit to 2 decimal places, however if that's not the case, I'd definitely go for your solution (and I voted up your answer :)).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would implement this with a for loop over an `int` variable `i`. Using integers avoids rounding problems due to the limitations of floating point arithmetic. [See [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).]

Let `i` run from `0` to `iFinish-1` and set `time` equal to `start + i*minor_interval`. The value of `iFinish` can be found by rounding `(finish-start)/minor_interval` to the nearest int.

Major axis updates can be handled in a similar way. Round `major_interval/minor_interval` to the nearest `int`, say `k`. Then update major axis marks every k-th iteration.

In terms of code it looks like this:

```
double round(double r) {
    return (r > 0.0) ? floor(r + 0.5) : ceil(r - 0.5);
}
...
int iFinish = round((finish-start)/minor_interval);
int k = round(major_interval/minor_interval);
for (int i=0; i<iFinish; i++)
{
    double time = start + i*minor_interval;
    bool isMajor = (i%k == 0);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your method of tolerance doesn't work is that it only accounts for when the stored value is slightly higher than it should be. (e.g. When it's 1.0001 instead of 1. If it's 0.999 instead of 1, your method won't work)

To fix this, check if it's within a tolerance on *either* side of the expected value.

So, instead of:

```
if (m == 0)
```

use:

```
if (m < small_value || major_interval - m < small_value)
```

where small_value is something like 1e-8.

Answer (score 0):

I would make the loop be a for loop using integers. Also you should avoid == operators for floats/doubles due to the unprecise nature of these tyes if numbers.

So to convert the doubles into integers for the purpose of the loop:

```
numIntervals = (int)((finish - start) / minor_intervals);
majIntervalsGap = numIntervals  / (int)((finish - start) / major_intervals);
double time = start;
for (int loop = 0;; loop < numIntervals; ++loop)
{
    bool isMajor = ((loop % majIntervalsGap) == 0);

    ... do you ourput here as you have the desired info for it
    time += minor_interval;
}
```

Comment: How does an (int) cast handle rounding? I'm reasonably sure it doesn't do round to nearest which is what is needed here.